# Please explain this strange behavior of jQuery draggables (in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I am seeing strange behavior of jQuery UI draggable elements using Chrome. In the code below, I create two colored blocks, which you can drag around in the browser window. Try it [here](http://omnium-gatherum.appspot.com/pages/dragbug.html). Everything works fine using IE8 and FF3, but with Chrome two bad things happen:

- When you click on either block, the
  cursor becomes an I-beam. Note there
  is no text on this page!
- Put one block right on top of the
  other (the green one's on top). Now
  click on the block and drag it.  The
  cursor turns into a [no symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol),
  but you can still drag. Now let go.
  **Instead of the block being dropped,
  it's still being dragged around even
  though the mouse button is now up**.

This seems like **way** too simple of an example to break Chrome or jQuery. 
Am I missing something?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('<div>').addClass(  'redsquare').appendTo('body').draggable({ grid: [24, 24] })
            $('<div>').addClass('greensquare').appendTo('body').draggable({ grid: [24, 24] })
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }

        .redsquare {
            position: absolute;  
            top: 48; left: 48;          
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            background-color: Red;
        }            

        .greensquare {
            position: absolute;  
            top: 48; left: 96;          
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            background-color: Green;
        }            
    </style>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently a bug in jQuery UI that was fixed in jQuery UI 1.8.6. You are using 1.7.2.

It wasn't stopping selection..

Reference posts:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-text-select-cursor-on-drag
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4163

One solution:

```
$(".ui-draggable").each(function() {
  this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
});
```

Comment: Although the links only addressed the minor text-cursor issue, updating to jQuery UI 1.8.6 fixed both problems. Thanks!

Comment: I think both issues were caused by the selection event though. As you clicked on one block, it thought you were selecting something (hence why it shows the I-beam cursor).  When one block was on top of the other and you tried to drag, it still thought you were trying to select something. For some reason, I don't think it stopped the selection event, which was why even when you let go it was still following the cursor.  Glad upgrading fixed it though!

Comment: +1 for solution presented on http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4163. If you put document.onselectstart = function(){ return false; }; in  the draggable "start" method and then, document.onselectstart = function(){}; in the "stop" method, it fixes it for when chrome selects anything anywhere while dragging.